# Imagemagick thumbnail

Tags: php, imagemagick, thumbnails

I am using this code to generate my thumbs.

But if I get the generated file and try to compress using a software I still get 30% average compression.

What else can I do to use thumbs recommended for web?

```
  $imagick = new \Imagick($arquivo_tmp);   
  $imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
  $imagick->setbackgroundcolor('rgb(255, 255, 255)');
  $imagick->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
  $imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(65);
  $imagick->thumbnailImage($largura_novo, $altura_novo, $proporcional, $fundo_fixo);
  $imagick->setInterlaceScheme(Imagick::INTERLACE_PLANE);
  $imagick->stripImage();
```

Comment: are you worried about file size?, are you saying when you take this image into Photoshop you can compress it even more?. If so that is to be expected

Comment: Are you using Q16 version? Upload some sample image for quick test.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I'm not sure how to explain my problem. But let's go.

I realized that setImageCompression () does not make a difference in the generated thumb.
I can even comment on this line that the final file size holds the same.

If I use the generated thumb in "jpegtran -copy none -progressive" the image can still be compressed by 9%

Comment: Generated Image Example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eq3ay0xjh2gb9gr/index.php.jpeg?dl=0